# With Bootstrap 5.3 how to change the max width of a single tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

I would like to change the max width of a Bootstrap Tooltip without changing the others. I don't use Sass or SCSS. I try many stuff based on the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#variables):

```
tooltip-max-width="300px"
bs-tooltip-max-width="300px"
data-bs-tooltip-max-width="300px"
data-bs-max-width="300px"
```

The Tooltip is initialized in my JS code. I also try to add the custom parameter in the option, but it does not work.

```
this.buttonTooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(this.buttonImageEl, { html: true, maxWidth: "300px" });
```

Does any one know how to do this?

Comment: typo `mawWidth` is not there in the original code, right?

Comment: @codeandcloud Thx, I updated the code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`maxWidth` is not a member of [`options`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/tooltips/#options). So the code won't work. But still you can use `customClass` in the `options`. You can set the value from both attribute and options.

```js
const fooEl = document.getElementById('foo');
new bootstrap.Tooltip(fooEl);

const barEl = document.getElementById('bar');
new bootstrap.Tooltip(barEl);

const bazEl = document.getElementById('baz');
const bazOptions = {
  customClass: 'from-opt'
};
new bootstrap.Tooltip(bazEl, bazOptions);
```

```css
.from-attr {
  --bs-tooltip-max-width: 100px !important;
}

.from-opt {
  --bs-tooltip-max-width: 75px !important;
}
.
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button id="foo" title="My loong toooltip">Default</button>
<button id="bar" title="My loong toooltip" data-bs-custom-class="from-attr">From Attribute</button>
<button id="baz" title="My loong toooltip">From Options</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

P.S: You should use the `!important`. Otherwise it's getting overriden.